# Pre and post hooks for factory - scope issue

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to build a simple factory that will pass "props" to modifiers registered to the parent.

However, in the code below, the `props` object is undefined by the time `posthooks()` gets called.

```js
const factory = function({ collection = [], modifiers = [] }) {
 let props = { collection, timesRan: 0 };
 const registerRun = () => {
  props.timesRan = props.timesRan + 1;
 }
 const prehooks = function() {
  modifiers.forEach((modifier) => {
   modifier.prehook(props);
   registerRun();
  });
 };
 const posthooks = function(props) {
  modifiers.forEach((modifier) => {
   modifier.posthook(props);
   registerRun();
  });
 };
 prehooks();
 posthooks();
 return props;
};
// test case
const collection = [
 {
  "name": "Jimmy",
  "id": 1
 },
 {
  "name": "Johnny",
  "id": 2
 },
]
// modifier
const modifier = {
 prehook: (props) => {
  if (props && props.collection) {
   console.log('pre hook ran');
   props.collection = props.collection.map(item => Object.assign({}, { points: 100 }, item));
  }
  return props;
 },
 posthook: (props) => {
  if (props && props.collection) {
   console.log('post hook ran');
   props.collection = props.collection.map(item => Object.assign({}, { id: String(item.id) }, item));
  }
  return props;
 }
}
// test the factory
const modifiers = [ modifier ];
const returnValue = factory({ collection, modifiers } );
console.log('returnValue', returnValue);
```

Comment: Your `props` argument to the `posthooks` function in the `factory` function shadows the `props` variable in the parent scope, and since `posthooks` is called without any arguments, the value of the `props` argument for the call is `undefined`. If you intentionally omitted the value for the `props` argument to `posthooks`, expecting the function to magically resolve the value using the `props` variable from the parent scope, your assumption is invalid -- values do not shadow values from parent scope, declarations do.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks. If you'd like to write a separate answer I'm happy to give you the resolution marker :)

Comment: I would be willing to write the solution as an answer if the error wasn't an oversight on your part and you genuinely expected the `props` of the parent scope to shadow the `props` argument for the `posthooks` in case the latter is omitted. I could explain how JavaScript works in this case, but I suspect it *was* an oversight, in which case this question is of very limited value to SO (in my opinion) and can safely be deleted (by you). Do tell which one is it, and I'll oblige if it's the former.